# As a Peruvian, can I apply for a USA visitors visa from outside of my home country?

Tags: usa, visa, peru

I'm Peruvian, and all the appointments for a US visitor visa in the embassy here in Peru have been taken, and I heard there are no more available dates until mid-2024.

Is it possible that I can apply in another country? Because of the situation in the country, I don't think they will open more slots for this year and I was wondering if I could get an interview outside of Peru.

I've never applied before for a USA visitor visa, I can wait, but if I manage to get an appointment for the next year I don't know what they will expect from me after a year in the interview.

Comment: This seems like more of a [Travel.SE] question than an [Expatriates.SE] question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you can apply outside of your country of residence. See the text below from the [US State Dept.](https://travel.state.gov/content/travel/en/us-visas/tourism-visit/visitor.html#:%7E:text=You%20should%20schedule%20an%20appointment,the%20country%20where%20you%20live.) :

> You should schedule an appointment for your visa interview at the U.S.
> Embassy or Consulate in the country where you live. You may schedule
> your interview at another U.S. Embassy or Consulate, but be aware that
> it may be more difficult to qualify for a visa outside of the country
> where you live.